# how set Button FontAwesome Icon with string in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I want to save the Button Icon in DB, I'd like to have something like:

```
Button button = new Button();
String icon = "FontAwesome.COGS";
button.setIcon(icon);
```

or

```
Button button = new Button();
String icon = "fonticon://FontAwesome/f013";
button.setIcon(new ThemeResource(icon));
```

what's the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Store the name of the icon in the DB and load it by name:

```
setIcon(FontAwesome.valueOf("COGS"))
```

This can fail with an `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with the following code

```
button.setIcon(FontAwesomeUtil.fromName("COG"));

public class FontAwesomeUtil {
    public static FontAwesome fromName(String name) {
        FontAwesome[] arr = FontAwesome.values();
        int len = arr.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            FontAwesome f = arr[i];
            if(f.name().equals(name)) {
                return f;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("name " + name + " not found in FontAwesome");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be more efficient to store the mapping between name and FontAwesome object in a HashMap once and work on the map after.